# How to send multi input data in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an input tag and an input select and if I click on a button an other input appear.
Then I wanted to post these data with AJAX.

http://jsfiddle.net/dsDmc/59/

that is my situation but I dont know How to send all my data with a `$.ajax()`

thx to all.

Comment: Parse the values and create a json object of them and post that.

Comment: Can you showb us the code that you've tried with and tell us what didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to a form, then post the form up with all of the inputs in.

```
<form id="form">
   <! -- Input Controls here -- >
</form>

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "yourURL",
     data: $("#form").serialize(),
}).done(function( msg ) {
     alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Also don't use `live` as it is deprecated. The preffered method is `on`.

Comment: thx Darren but I have a redirection with the form tag.. How could I stop this redirection ?

Comment: You can return false or remove the action property.